# Python-memcache connection timeout

Tags: python, timeout, memcached

How do I reduce the connection timeout for python-memcache?

When a machine in my cluster goes down, the healthy machines hang for too long trying to connect to it.

Is settimeout the only way?

Answer (score 0):

After adjusting time out, also adjust number of retries per server before purging it from the pool.

Comment: python-memcache does not appear to have a timeout OR max retries setting, hence my question.

Comment: I assume you have to wrap it then with your own code that will check for LibMemcached response and adjust accordingly (for retries)

Comment: Unless anyone else wants to chime in then, the answer is "no" you cannot adjust connection timeouts and automatic retries using python-memcache.

Comment: You don't have to adjust retries on python-memcache, you can do it in your own code...